# PostgreSQL Failed login attempts

Tags: database, postgresql, security

How can I Specifies the number of failed login attempts in PostgreSQL before the role or user is locked and unlock after a time that I want?

What about blocking IP not user. If I want ban IP after n login attempt fail, what is your suggestion and solution?

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Postgres has no built in mechanism for this. It would need to come from a third party program.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Thank you. Can you give me your suggestion?

Comment: You will need to provide more information: 1) Are you using an existing framework in front of the database  or custom code? 2) What programing language or languages are you using? Add information as update to question.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I want to provide postgres as a service and just give connection string to users and I will be admin of service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL has no built-in capabilities to avoid brute force password attacks, except for [auth_delay](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-delay.html).

Comment: What about blocking IP not user. If I want ban IP after n login attempt fail, what is your suggestion and solution?

Comment: I have no good suggestions. Perhaps you find something in [this thread](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/61463e206b7c4c0ca17b03a59e890b78%40lmco.com).

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to implement that behavior directly in PostgreSQL.

What you could do is take a look at [Fail2Ban](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban), you can set it up so that it scans the PostgreSQL log files and bans IPs after some failed authentication attempts (you can configure it to fit your needs).